# Proof that there are at the most two numbers of exactly six digits that squared end with the same six digits

Tags: divisibility, congruences, natural-numbers

Written in a more formal way, proof that there are at the most $2$ numbers $n$ of six digits, that

$$n^2 \equiv n \mod 10^6$$

Research effort:

if $n^2 \equiv n \mod 10^6$ this means $10^6\mid n^2-n \rightarrow10^6\mid n(n-1)$

Given that $5^6\mid 10^6$ then $5^6\mid n(n-1)$ whitch means $5^6\mid n$ or $5^6\mid n-1$

Same for $2^6$, Given that $2^6\mid 10^6$ then $2^6\mid n(n-1)$ whitch means $2^6\mid n$ or $2^6\mid n-1$

By the chinese remainder theorem I got assured $4$ solutions, but I tried to solve the systems and it's not a very happy thing to do, so I think I did something wrong somewhere.

What do you think?

Comment: Two of the solutions are $0$ and $1$.  You are looking for the other two.

Comment: Note that if you have $2^6|n$ and $5^6|n+1$ then you have also $2^6|10^6-n$ and $5^6|10^6-n-1$ giving you a second pair of consecutive numbers which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\displaystyle2^6|(n-a)$ and $5^6|(n-a),$

$\displaystyle$ lcm$(2^6,5^6)|(n-a)$

As $(2,5)=1,(2^6,5^6)=(2,5)^6=1$

$\implies$ lcm$(2^6,5^6)=(2^6\cdot5^6)=10^6\iff n\equiv a\pmod{10^6}$

Here $a=0,1$